# Keyboard stops working on start menu

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, start-menu

does anyone know a solution for win10 keyboard stops working a while after startup.

Recently my laptop showed an error code 800700CI / 800700C1 with a script:  ..\AppData\Roaming\isMiner\minerstart.vbs

and i searched for the solution online but couldn't get anything on it. And then shortly after that when i restart my laptop, the start menu works for a while(with typing) then stops when i want to type anything. Like say i want to type control panel but doesn't work.

Also when i want to decrease the brightness level with a button, it doesn't work.

Please help

Comment: Do you use the isMiner? Or know what it is?

Comment: I dont know what it is, so i removed it from the script

Comment: Also found Minerstart in Task Manager in the startup tab being enable and not measured... tried disabling since it had no publisher but didn't work.

Comment: Sounds  like you should run a virus scan.

Comment: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](//superuser.com/q/100360)

Comment: A licensed BitDefender couldn't detect the virus upon scanning

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue. Works fine now.

Did a factory reset of my PC with keeping personal files which in then re-installed the OS back to its original state when purchased.

Firstly, backed up my personal files just to be sure and the applications such as MS office installations and did the factory reset which helped a lot.

I followed this video to Resetting the PC

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LgHNRjiekQ